# Load jQuery actions when page opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, hide

This script isn't executed when the page is loaded, only when changing between the different drop down options. What should I do to make it .hide() the case 0: fields from the start?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").change(function () {

        var selectedIndex = jQuery("DROPDOWNID']").prop('selectedIndex');

        switch (selectedIndex) {
            case 0:
                jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').hide("fast");

                break;
            case 1:
                jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').show("fast");
                break;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Just move the code outside of the `change` handler.

Comment: Also, if you're selecting by ID then there will only be 1 of each element with that ID, so you can just do `$("#ID")`

Comment: wellcome to SO, please remember to mark answers that solve your problems as accepted. Otherwise, your question will remain unanswered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").trigger("change");`. This way you could ***reuse*** your logic.

Your code looks like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").change(function () {

        var selectedIndex = jQuery("DROPDOWNID']").prop('selectedIndex');

        switch (selectedIndex) {
            case 0:
                jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').hide("fast");

                break;
            case 1:
                jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').show("fast");
                break;
        }
    });

    jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Is the selectedIndex always 0 when the page loads?  I didn't see him mention that in the question.

Comment: @Archer: `the case 0: fields from the start?`. I hope I understand correctly?

Comment: Thank you Khanh!! Worked perfect with .trigger("change");

Comment: That doesn't mean that the 1st item is selected.

Comment: Archer: The first option in drop down is selected when page is loaded. Or what do you mean?

Comment: @Archer: the change handler should handle all the cases. And there should be one case selected when page loads. This way, you could reuse your logic. For example, when you change your default selected when page loads is 1, the logic is updated accordingly.

Comment: It's okay - you're not understanding the point I'm making.  Your answer fits these particular circumstances so the OP is happy - that's what counts :)

Answer (score 0):

Add below line before change handler.

```
jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').hide();
```

so code would be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').hide("fast");

    jQuery("select[id='DROPDOWNID']").change(function ()
    {
        var selectedIndex = jQuery("DROPDOWNID']").prop('selectedIndex');
        switch (selectedIndex)
        {
            case 0:
                jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').hide("fast");
                break;
            case 1:
                jQuery("input[id='IDFROMSHAREPOINT']").closest('tr').show("fast");
                break;
        }
    });
});
```